# MongoDB PHP connection not working

Tags: php, mongodb

```
<?php

$m = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost', array(
    'username'  => 'wa',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'db'        => 'wa'
));
```

I'm using that code snippet to connect and am trying to run commands in PHP to insert / find data in a MongoDB collection or database.

I installed MongoDB and added the mongo.so extension to my php.ini.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not getting an error.  Turning on display errors now.

Comment: This should throw a `MongoConnnectionException` if it can't connect.

Comment: http://puu.sh/6Ms3R.png from my phpinfo();

Comment: @rid no the package is called mongo

Comment: @user3093095: What, exactly is "not working". The only code you've shared is construction of a MongoClient object. If that doesn't yield any PHP errors or an exception, then the connection most likely succeeded and you should attempt to do your commands/inserts/finds/etc. You can also utilize [MongoLog](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongolog.php) to watch what the driver is doing internally.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run just the connection code from the command line. Also you should be passing in your connection options in this format:

> mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2:],...]/db

Use this:

```
<?php

  $m = new MongoClient('mongodb://wa:password@localhost/wa');

?>
```

That will throw any errors you are having on the command line and be easy to diagnose. The responses should be self explainatory. Likely causes:

1. You are connecting to `localhost` and do not have a running `mongod` or `mongos` on this machine. [ So change tha host and possibly port].
2. Your user credentials are incorrect

It seems likely that case 1 applies by the very fact you are supplying user credentials, as you would be unlikely to need them if developing on your own machine. It would also be very uncommon to be running MongoDB on the same server as your application in production.

Comment: Using an `$options` array (as in the OP) and embedding auth credentials in the `$server` string are both perfectly valid. If anything, the `$options` array can be more reliable if the password has special characters in it that might goof up the parsing.

Comment: @jmikola Agreed on the connection format being valid as it was. I was mainly drawing attention to the fact that it was likely that the `localhost` connection was not true and more likely that this was a remote host.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that stumbles upon this, the MongoClient is depricated and does not work with the current (as of Aug 2018) MongoDB PHP Driver. (which would be installed with the mongodb.dll file, not the *.so file)

A current example of a working connection would be:

```
<?php

$user = "XXXX";
$pwd = 'XXXX';
$filter = [];

if (isset($_POST['needleID'])) {
    $needleID = $_POST['needleID'];
    $filter = ['id'=> $needleID];
} 

//Manager Class
$connection = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://${user}:${pwd}@localhost:27017");

// Query Class
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);

// Output of the executeQuery will be object of MongoDB\Driver\Cursor class
$rows = $connection->executeQuery('sedwe.defaultConfig', $query);

// Convert rows to Array and sedn result back to client
$rowsArr = $rows->toArray();
echo json_encode($rowsArr);
?>
```